# Android, startAcitivity for result produces weird flow

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to know what is going on in following case + FIX.

Somehow after calling
`fragment.startActivityForResult` -> code reaches first `onActivityResult` (on fragment, with result 0=CANCELED), then inside second Activity.
Same stuff if I use `getActivity()`.`startActivityForResult`.. I checked with debugger. After I respond from second Activity, code won't reach `onActivityResult` (like it was "consumed"?)

I am building a Launcher app, my activities have some crap in `Manifest`, but don't think it is from there.

```
<activity android:name=".ui.home.HomeActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:stateNotNeeded="true"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"/>

<activity android:name=".ui.apps.AppsActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:stateNotNeeded="true"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>
```

This is how I create the intent

```
intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AppsActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(AppsActivity.KEY_PICK_APP, true);
getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent,BottomShortcutsFragment.REQUEST_CODE_PICK_APP);
```

This is how I respond

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(KEY_SELECTED_APP, packageName);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

---

UPDATE#1
It is from Manifest, it works if I remove from second activity the android:launchMode="singleTask"

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.apps.AppsActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:stateNotNeeded="true"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```

Comment: Please shore all relevant methods. All code should be inside a class and method. This is Java after all.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are calling startActivityForResult() in a Fragment. In your code, result will return to Activity, not fragment.

So, try to use like this:

```
intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AppsActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(AppsActivity.KEY_PICK_APP, true);
startActivityForResult(intent,BottomShortcutsFragment.REQUEST_CODE_PICK_APP);
```

Comment: I know about that.. it wasn't it.. Anyway, seems to be from something in manifest.